# Getting Warning in console eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, console, warnings

```
Starting ChromeDriver 106.0.5249.61 (511755355844955cd3e264779baf0dd38212a4d0-refs/branch-heads/5249@{#569}) on port 49652
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 07, 2022 1:44:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Oct 07, 2022 1:44:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 106, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
Oct 07, 2022 1:44:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 106.
Oct 07, 2022 1:44:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.1.2` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post your code and URL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.